# Documentation search does not work through right-click in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, documentation, texdoc

I'm relatively new with LaTeX and I can't find the solution to a problem I came through only recently.

I'm using TeXLive 2015 with the editor TeXstudio, which I updated to the most recent version (2.10.8) a couple days ago, after a while I was using the version 2.10.0. 
My problem is that the documentation search that is accessible by right-clicking to a package name is not working anymore, since the following message is showing up:

> texdoc did not respond to query on package: babel

The search worked perfectly with the previous version I had. Moreover, texdoc works when I launch it through the command window: i.e. writing the command line

`texdoc babel`

opens the documentation as expected.

Searching a bit through the Web led me to some questions about the same problem (you can read it [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/thread/1b641019/) and [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1193/)), but I can't figure out how the solution works. I assume some modifications must be done to the TeXstudio configuration, and I tried to add the texdoc folder path to the TeXstudio commands as it is suggested, but I must have failed something, since this had no effect.

Where am I wrong?

**EDIT**: I uninstalled and reinstalled TeXstudio, but the problem still remains.
I forgot to specify I am using Windows 10.

Comment: I am using the same TeXStudio version and the documentation for Babel works fine. So, I guess it's not a software bug. If it works in the command line, then you don't have the path problem. The links you said are more targeting the search path parameters.

Comment: @Winsoft : thank you for commenting. Just to be clear, the malfunctioning regards every package documentation, not only babel's. Maybe something went wrong with the installation... I'll try to reinstall TeXstudio.

Comment: Please see here if you get some fix or reopen, if you think it is a bug with Windows 10: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1193/ and https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/thread/1b641019/

Comment: same here: I'm guessing you have a space in the path? texdoc gui and texstudio don't seem to like that.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi : thank you for your input and sorry for the late reply. Those are the same discussions I skimmed through while I was searching for a solution some time ago, but I never figured out how to make it work because I couldn't find the _Additional Search Paths -> Commands ($PATH)_ line in _Config_. I always overlooked the advanced options. Now I added the folder in which texdoc is located and everything works fine!

Comment: @naphaneal : thank you for your comment and sorry for the late reply. Everything is working fine now: I've put the texdoc folder path into the _Additional Search Paths -> Commands ($PATH)_ line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem following the discussions provided at [this link](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1193/). The `Additional Search Paths -> Commands ($PATH)` is under `Advanced options`.